# Placeholder delete on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, placeholder

I´m using the "placeholder" attr. for placeholder text in input-fields

I need to have this functionality in IE-incarnations too.

I want the Placeholder to hide on FOCUS! every workaround i found hides the placeholder when the first type is entered.

I´m unable to work it out myself, it needs to simply delete the input´s Placeholder-Text on focus but also recovers that placeholder-text on blur if input-value is empty.

I´m trying to put this to work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
  input = jQuery(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
    input.removeClass('placeholder');
    input.attr('placeholder','')
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = jQuery(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
  }
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
    var input = jQuery(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
    }
  })
});


});
```

this changes the value of the placeholder to "(nothing)"  and the behaviour is as i want but on blur it cant recover the placeholder-value beacause its "(nothing)" now

//Update

the solution for me :

```
$(function()
{
  $('input').each(function() 
  {
     $(this).val($(this).attr('holder'));
  });

  $('input').focus(function()
  {
    if($(this).attr('holder')==$(this).val())
    {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });
  $('input').focusout(function()
  {
     if($.trim($(this).val())=='')
     {
       var holder = $(this).attr('holder');
       $(this).val(holder);
     }
  });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `placeholder` you can use the code below or use this simple jQuery plugin:
 [**jQuery Placeholder**](https://github.com/blacksrc/jQuery-Placeholder).

 **[jsFiddle Live Demo Of Code Below](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/FdjJv/2/)**
**HTML**

```
<input type='text' holder='First name'><br>
<input type='text' holder='Last name'><br>
<input type='text' holder='Age'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  $('input').each(function() {
     $(this).val($(this).attr('holder'));
  });

  $('input').focus(function() {
    if($(this).attr('holder')==$(this).val()) {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });

  $('input').focusout(function() {
     if($.trim($(this).val())=='') {
       var holder = $(this).attr('holder');
       $(this).val(holder);
     }
  });
});
```

Also you can use this simple jQuery plugin: [jQuery Placeholder](https://github.com/blacksrc/jQuery-Placeholder).

Comment: IE lte 9 and opera did´nt initialy have the value of attr('holder') fixed this with adding $('#selector').val($('#selector').attr('holder')); outside of function

Comment: nice, that each loop is much more prototypely than my try

Answer (score 3):

Use the placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search here">
```

For browsers that do not support `placeholder`; you can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill)

Comment: i´m doing so, need tat functionality in ie-incarnations too, take a look at my edited question

Comment: there must be an easier solution, have a look at my edits and thanks for your time

Comment: there is nothing easier than adding `placeholder="whatever"`; in the case of IE, simply adding a polyfill via yepnope should not give you any problems. remember that those polyfills have been tested thoroughly and will probably perform better than an 'easier' solution. Having it disappear `onkeydown` is standard behavior, don't alienate your users by changing that :)

Comment: i don´t want the placeholder to exist anymore on focus, the functionality of placeholder="" let´s the placeholder hide when i type into the field and not on focus

Answer (score 2):

Old and not the best way is:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="Enter text here" onFocus="if (this.value=='Enter text here'){this.value='';}"
onBlur="if (this.value==''){this.value='Enter text here';}" />
```

But it works even in IE6.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i was searching for

Comment: Remember to clear placeholder values on submit, otherwise the server will receive dummy values.

Answer (score 2):

For Webkit based browsers and Firefox you can hide the placeholder in pure CSS:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { opacity:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number polyfills out there that will "add" placeholder functionality in browsers that do not support it. I've used [jQuery Placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) in the past, but there are quite a few others mentioned in the [modernizr docs](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) (scroll down to the section on placeholders).

The nice thing about jQuery Placeholder is that you shouldn't have to change/add any code aside from a reference to the library. Just add the `placeholder` attribute to your element.

Comment: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder  theres also that behaviour, i dont want to have, really didnt find a script that removes and adds placeholder on focus and blur

Answer (score 0):

here is my code to hide placeholder text on input and textarea focus(). Simple and working great.

```js
$('textarea,input').focus(function(e){
    val=$(this).attr('value');
    if (!val)
    $(this).attr('value',' ');
    this.select();
}).blur(function(e){
    val=$(this).attr('value');
    if (val==' ')
    $(this).attr('value','');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use these 2 methods (jquery) to hide placeholder when the input gets focus, and when it loses focus and it is empty show placeholder.

input.focus

- step-1: simply saving placeholder value into a universal variable( here pl)
- step-2: set placeholder property of input to ''

input.focusout

- step-1: set placeholder property of input to the saved variable(here pl)

  ```
   var pl;
  //on getting focus
  $('input').focus(function(){
    pl=$(this).prop('placeholder');
    $(this).prop('placeholder','');
  });
  // on losing focus:
  $('input').focusout(function(){    
    $(this).prop('placeholder',pl);
  });
  ```

Comment: Only code in answer is not enough. Some explanation is required.